# how would one not use `this` in a JavaScript object {}?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

in [Norway this year](https://vimeo.com/97419177) Doug Crawford announced that he no longer uses `this` in JavaScript (or did he mean ES6?). Sincerely, how would one not use `this` here:

```
var indexViewModel = {

    currentIndex: ko.observable(0),
    currentPage: ko.observable(1),
    displayItems: ko.observableArray(),

    indexSegmentsForPeople: [
        { id: "poetryinxhtml", text: "Poetry in XHTML5" },
        { id: "poetryinpdf", text: "Poetry in PDF" },
        { id: "poetryinstreams", text: "Poetry in Streams" },
        { id: "digitizedart", text: "Digitized Art" }
    ],
    indexSegmentsForTime: [
        { id: "prose", text: "Prose" },
        { id: "interviewsanddocumentary", text: "Interviews/Documentary" },
        { id: "therasxcontext", text: "the rasx() context" }
    ],
    indexVisitorLinks: [
        { url: "./rasx01.html", title: "about the kinté space" },
        { url: "./kfaqs.html", title: "kinté FAQs" },
        { url: "./khits.html", title: "kinté hits" },
        { url: "./rasx00.html", title: "the kinté space oddity" }
    ],
    items: [],
    itemsCount: ko.observable(0),
    itemsPerPage: 9,
    pageCount: ko.observable(0),

    getCurrentIndex: function () {
        return ((this.currentPage() - 1) * this.itemsPerPage);
    },
    getJSON: function (id) {
        var url = this.getIndexJsonUrl(id);
        var that = this;
        return $.getJSON(url).then(function (data) {
            that.setItems(data);
        });
    },
    getJSONforVisitors: function () {
        var that = this;
        return $.getJSON('./data/VisitorThumbs.json').then(function (data) {
            that.setItemsForVisitors(data);
        });
    },
    getIndexJsonUrl: function (id) {
        return './data/index-' + id + '.json';
    },
    getIsNewValue: function (pubDate) {
        var now = new Date();
        var test1 = ((now.getMonth() - pubDate.getMonth()) <= 2);
        var test2 = (pubDate.getFullYear() === now.getFullYear());
        return (test1 && test2);
    },
    getSlice: function () {
        return this.items.slice(this.currentIndex(),
                (this.currentIndex() + this.itemsPerPage));
    },
    isNextPageEnabled: ko.observable(true),
    isPreviousPageEnabled: ko.observable(false),
    setDisplayItems: function () {
        var that = this;
        var slice = this.getSlice();
        this.displayItems.remove(function (item) { return item; });
        _(slice).each(function (item) { that.displayItems.push(item); });
    },
    setEnabled: function () {
        this.isNextPageEnabled(this.currentPage() < this.pageCount());
        this.isPreviousPageEnabled(this.currentPage() > 1);
    },
    setItems: function (data) {
        var that = this;
        this.items = _(data.ChildDocuments)
            .sortBy(function (d) { return $.rx.dateTime.getJsonDate(d.CreateDate); }).reverse();

        _(this.items).each(function (item) {
            //Add .isNew property:
            var pubDate = $.rx.dateTime.getJsonDate(item.CreateDate);
            item.isNew = that.getIsNewValue(pubDate);
        });

        this.currentIndex(0);
        this.currentPage(1);
        this.itemsCount(this.items.length);
        this.pageCount(Math.ceil(this.itemsCount() / this.itemsPerPage));
        this.setDisplayItems();
        this.setEnabled();
    },
    setItemsForVisitors: function (data) {
        this.items = data.ChildDocuments;

        this.currentIndex(0);
        this.currentPage(1);
        this.itemsCount(this.items.length);
        this.pageCount(Math.ceil(this.itemsCount() / this.itemsPerPage));
        this.setDisplayItems();
        this.setEnabled();
    },
    setNextPage: function () {
        this.currentPage(this.currentPage() + 1);
        this.setEnabled();
        if (this.currentPage() > this.pageCount()) { this.currentPage(this.pageCount()); }
        this.currentIndex(this.getCurrentIndex());
        this.setDisplayItems();
    },
    setNextPageClickGate: function () {
        if (this.isNextPageEnabled()) { this.setNextPage(); } else { return false; }
    },
    setPreviousPage: function () {
        this.currentPage(this.currentPage() - 1);
        this.setEnabled();
        if (this.currentPage() < 1) { this.currentPage(1); }
        this.currentIndex(this.getCurrentIndex());
        this.setDisplayItems();
    },
    setPreviousPageClickGate: function () {
        if (this.isPreviousPageEnabled()) { this.setPreviousPage(); } else { return false; }
    },
    triggerAfterAdd: function (item, iterator) {
        $(window.document).trigger('afterAdd',
            ['IndexFlowTemplate', item, iterator]);
    }
};
```

???

Comment: Not sure what he meant, but you can use `indexViewModel` everywhere you used `this`.

Comment: Maybe he meant that he doesn't use prototypal inheritance. I'm not sure many people are going to be willing to sit through an hour long video just to catch the point at which he makes that statement, so it would help a lot if you'd note the relevant timestamp in the video.

Comment: Just because you can doesn't mean you should?

Comment: Crockford says lots of things that I find silly.

Comment: I think he didn't mean he uses `this` when referencing to the global window object

Comment: I agree with cookie monster.  I've said it before, and I'll say it again: Crockford has definitely advanced the conversation about JavaScript, but not everything that falls out of his mouth is gold.

Comment: It's at about the 18minute point, but it seems to be a requirement of his AdSafe system, and seems to be an avoidance of functions which use `this`, to avoid exposing the global object.

Comment: I agree too - Crockford has a lot of very valid points, but sometimes seems to confuse his personal style with absolute correctness. A good example is that he never wants you to use ++ because lesser programmers might not understand the operator. Cynical and silly.

Comment: Crockford believes that, once *he* has been bitten by something, nobody should ever use it again because it is "tricky". I have a lot of respect for him, but some of his ideas about what constitutes tricky or dangerous code are pretty silly. There are obviously best practices, and we should stick to them, but his bar for deciding which language features should *never be used by anybody* is ridiculously low.

Comment: Also TLDR on video: Crockford thinks that `new` is evil (and therefore `this` as well) because it's possible to try to write `x = new Ctor()` and forget the `new`, accidentally writing `x = Ctor()`. `Ctor` will run without error, with `this` set to `window` (or other global object) and also because `new`/`this` has no truly private members. Instead, Crockford would write `function Ctor() { var private = {}; return { getName: function () { return private.name }; }` and create class instances with `x = Ctor()`. [Source](http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/bad-parts.html)

Comment: @DavidThomas It sounds like avoiding `this` to prevent exposing the global object was the original impetus, but I think he ran with the idea because `this` can create unpredictable behavior and therefore is a source of a lot of bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your snippet doesn't look particularly idiomatic to me. It's rather like Java code translated to Javascript pretty straightforwardly. In JS the usual "code unit" (code+data) is a closure, not an object:

```
var indexViewModel = (function() {

    var
        currentIndex = ko.observable(0),
        currentPage = ko.observable(1),
        etc...

    function getCurrentIndex() {
        return (currentPage() - 1) * itemsPerPage;
    };

    function getJSON(id) {
        var url = getIndexJsonUrl(id);
        return $.getJSON(url).then(function (data) {
            setItems(data);
        });
    };

    etc....

    return {
        // whatever needs to be public
    };

})();
```

Basically, all "object members" became local variables, and "private methods" = local functions. As you can see, there's no need for `this` (let alone `that=this`) at all. The code is much simpler and cleaner.

Comment: I have *JavaScript the Good Parts* and will look for something along the lines of "In JS the usual "code unit" (code+data) is a closure, not an object" because this is very, very important and I seem to have missed out on this...

Comment: @rasx: for clarity, I wasn't quoting Crockford on this, it's my own point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking?  Crockford would not write code anything like that.  His code simply doesn't use `this`. It's a design thing - I mean, sure, you can take code that was written in a traditional object-oriented style and excise the `this`'s, but you'll get a mess.  You have to redesign the whole thing.

Crockford simply treats all method calls as if they were function calls; there's no receiver, only the arguments passed in.  Objects are treated as hashes, and their properties only accessed from the outside.  If a bit of code needs to refer to private values, it uses closures over local variables.

And no, it has nothing to do with ES6.  It seems the only thing that ES6 is changing about how he codes, aside from a few minor conveniences like the implicit object property initialization, is that he will be using tail recursion to eliminate loops.